# Map an array to each item in another array? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to generate some predictable URL's for a crawler.

I have a set of base urls:

```
base_urls = ['http://something.com/john', 
             'http://something.com/sally']
```

and each one has a unique url for their daily calendar:

```
to_append = ['-mon-calendar', 
             '-tues-calendar', 
             '-wed-calendar', 
             '-thurs-calendar', 
             '-fri-calendar']
```

I need to generate a new array containing a complete list of the all people's weekly calendars (e.g. `'http://something.com/john-mon-calendar',...`

I could iterate through this the long way but assume it's possible to do it more efficiently with `map()`. I haven't used map much and doing it with two iterables is throwing me off. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to create the Cartesian product between your lists, then `join` each item within a list comprehension.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [''.join(i) for i in product(base_urls, to_append)]
['http://something.com/john-mon-calendar',
 'http://something.com/john-tues-calendar',
 'http://something.com/john-wed-calendar',
 'http://something.com/john-thurs-calendar',
 'http://something.com/john-fri-calendar',
 'http://something.com/sally-mon-calendar',
 'http://something.com/sally-tues-calendar',
 'http://something.com/sally-wed-calendar',
 'http://something.com/sally-thurs-calendar',
 'http://something.com/sally-fri-calendar']
```

Answer (score 1):

No libraries:

```
links = [[url + day for day in to_append] for url in base_urls]
links_flattened = sum(links, [])
```